# React get Text inside of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the text content of the react element. In the example below, I want get: `hello 1`

```
var node = <myComponent id={1} />

class myComponent extends React.Component {

render() {
  return {
    <span> hello {this.props.id} </span>
  }
}
```

I tried to use `node.text` or `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node).textContent`, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not react-native code, have you wrongly tagged this question?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should modify your code like below :

```
<myComponent id={1} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your code using:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent id={1} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Your code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <span>Hello {this.props.id}</span>;
  }
}
```

Link to this code in a Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/class-component-dv6fj